# How do i alert the textbox input to a user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If i had a button and an input field. How would i alert whatever is in the input field to the user, when the button is clicked.

Explain your code please.
Make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Just google the onclick event man...

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i can make the button alert a message of my choice whenever i click it when using the onclick event. But i dont know how to make it alert whats in the input box

Comment: Let's say `<input type="text" id="myinput"/>` then in your `onclick` button code add this `alert( $("#myinput").val())`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button onclick="displayEnteredText()">Display</button>
<script>
  function displayEnteredText() {
    var inputText = document.getElementById("input"); // get the element with id "input" which is the textField
    alert(inputText.value); // show the value of the input in alert message
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you . i read through it and understood it. My issue was i did not know the function document.getElementById  . Need to learn more html/js.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
     <input id="name" value="">
     <input type="button" value="show me the name" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('name').value)">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Another possible approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var buttonElement = document.getElementById('button');
            buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
                alert(document.getElementById('name').value);
            });
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
 <input id="name" value="">
 <input id="button" type="button" value="show me the name">
</body>
</html>
```

With the second approach you can separate responsabilities, one person can create de html, and another person can focus in create javascript code.

Exists several ways to do this, but with two examples i think is enough in the current context

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<input type="text" name="basicText" id="alertInput">
<button class="alertButton">Click me!</button>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(".alertButton").click(function(){
        var value = $("#alertInput").val();
        alert(value + " was entered");
    });
</script>
```

In order to show what you typed in your alert, you need to reference the value inside the textbox. Since jquery is tagged in the post, I used it to get what's in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="btnclick" style="width:100px" value="Click Me" />
<input type="text" id="txtbox">
```

**JS**

```
$("#btnclick").click(function(){
var txtvalue = $("#txtbox").val();
alert("User enter " + txtvalue);
})
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5c4mL0cg/)